# Angular 7 / Typescript error: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-6, compiladores

Eu tenho uma função que roda ao realizar o *upload* de arquivos, entanto estou tendo um erro no `result` dentro da função `onload`.

Esse erro não faz sentido pois seu eu dar um `console.log` no `result` o resultado aparece claramente, então me parece um falso positivo perante o compilador do angular, que acusa o erro e não compila o programa.

Para poder rodar eu estou comentando aquela linha e removendo o comentário, por que por algum motivo depois da aplicação rodando ele acusa o erro mas não com gravidade suficiente para a parar.

```
async uploadFile(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = ((file: any) => {
      return (e: Event) => {
        let result = e.srcElement.result;
        //aqui acontece o erro e impede de compilar mas não existe erro de fato.
      }
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi muito simples, somente remover o tipo `Event` da variável `e` e adicionar `any`.

```
async uploadFile(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    let file = event.target.files[0];

    reader.onload = ((file: any) => {
      return (e: any) => {
        let result = e.srcElement.result;
        //aqui acontece o erro e impede de compilar mas não existe erro de fato.
      }
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
```

Solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Com `Typescript` eu ainda não programei, porem em `javascript` eu utilizo algo como mostrado no código abaixo, acho que pode te ajudar. =D

```
var reader = new FileReader(),
    file = event.target.files[0];

reader._file = file;    /// Guardo a referencia do file na propria FileReader
reader.onload = function(e){
    var self = this,          /// FileReader
        file = self._file,    /// referencia que guardei
        data = self.result;   /// Dados do resultado do reader

}

reader.readAsText(reader._file);
```

Comment: Vou me basear no seu exemplo, obrigada.